# Setting parsley().options.trigger won't work

Tags: parsley.js

```
// this works
$myInput.attr('data-parsley-trigger', 'change').parsley();

// this won't 
$myInput.parsley().options.trigger = 'change';
// but this works
$myInput.parsley().options.myCustomValidator = parameters;
```

The first approach works but it looks kind of hacky. I found an issue mentioning the second approach, but it won't work with `trigger` option.

Is it a bug or my setting is somehow wrong.